# Keras CONV1D: Error when checking target: expected decoded output to have shape (50, 50) but got array with shape (50, 1)

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I have this trouble: Error when checking target: expected decoded_output to have shape (50, 50) but got array with shape (50, 1) With this code, an autoencoder with CONV1D and two output, but the trouble is the reconstruction output (decode_output):

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

TAM_VECTOR = X_train.shape[1]

input_tweet = Input(shape=(TAM_VECTOR,X_train.shape[2]))

encoded = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu')(input_tweet)
encoded = Conv1D(32, kernel_size=1, activation='relu')(encoded)

decoded = Conv1D(32, kernel_size=1, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Conv1D(TAM_VECTOR, kernel_size=1, activation='relu', name='decode_output')(decoded)

encoded = Flatten()(encoded)
second_output = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='second_output')(encoded)

autoencoder = Model(inputs=input_tweet, outputs=[decoded, second_output])

autoencoder.compile(optimizer="adam",
                    loss={'decode_output': 'mse', 'second_output': 'mse'},
                    loss_weights={'decode_output': 0.001, 'second_output': 0.999},
                    metrics=["mae"])

autoencoder.fit([X_train], [X_train, y_train], epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

The input (X) has shape (50000,50) but since Conv1D recives a 3D input I reshape to:

```
X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], X.shape[1], -1))
```

(50000,50,1)

And y (the second output) is

```
y.shape
```

(50000,1)

And here the model summary

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_43 (InputLayer)           (None, 50, 1)        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_169 (Conv1D)             (None, 50, 64)       128         input_43[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_170 (Conv1D)             (None, 50, 32)       2080        conv1d_169[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_171 (Conv1D)             (None, 50, 32)       1056        conv1d_170[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_172 (Conv1D)             (None, 50, 64)       2112        conv1d_171[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_62 (Flatten)            (None, 1600)         0           conv1d_170[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
decode_output (Conv1D)          (None, 50, 50)       3250        conv1d_172[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pib_output (Dense)              (None, 1)            1601        flatten_62[0][0]                 
==================================================================================================
Total params: 10,227
Trainable params: 10,227
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

TAM_VECTOR should be replaced with 1 in the following line.

Replace

```
decoded = Conv1D(TAM_VECTOR, kernel_size=1, activation='relu', name='decode_output')(decoded)
```

with

```
decoded = Conv1D(1, kernel_size=1, activation='relu', name='decode_output')(decoded)
```

The decoded output shape should match the input shape of the AutoEncoder (50,1).

```
from keras.layers import Conv1D, Flatten, Dense, Input
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

TAM_VECTOR = 50
input_tweet = Input(shape=(TAM_VECTOR,1))

encoded = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu')(input_tweet)
encoded = Conv1D(32, kernel_size=1, activation='relu')(encoded)

decoded = Conv1D(32, kernel_size=1, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Conv1D(1, kernel_size=1, activation='relu', name='decode_output')(decoded)

encoded = Flatten()(encoded)
second_output = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='second_output')(encoded)

autoencoder = Model(inputs=input_tweet, outputs=[decoded, second_output])

autoencoder.compile(optimizer="adam",
                    loss={'decode_output': 'mse', 'second_output': 'mse'},
                    loss_weights={'decode_output': 0.001, 'second_output': 0.999},
                    metrics=["mae"])

autoencoder.fit(np.ones((1,50,1)), [np.ones((1,50,1)), np.ones((1,1))])
```

1/1 [==============================] - 0s 407ms/step - loss: 0.9112 - decode_output_loss: 0.9549 - second_output_loss: 0.9111 - decode_output_mean_absolute_error: 0.9772 - second_output_mean_absolute_error: 0.9545

Comment: Thanks for answering. I try to put 1, but I have this error: InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'second_output_sample_weights_13' with dtype float and shape [?]
  [[{{node second_output_sample_weights_13}}]]
  [[metrics_13/mean_absolute_error_1/Mean_1/_2173]]
  (1) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'second_output_sample_weights_13' with dtype float and shape [?]
  [[{{node second_output_sample_weights_13}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

Comment: Also, I don't have the same error in each execution. Running the same code without any change it can appear different errors. InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'decode_output_target_17' with dtype float and shape [?,?,?]
  [[{{node decode_output_target_17}}]]

Comment: This two errors but changing the name of the layer "decode_output" or "second_output":  
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'second_output_target_17' with dtype float and shape [?,?,?]
  [[{{node second_output_target_17}}]]

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue you're facing. I've pasted the code that I'm running with the output. Please check.

Comment: Hi, I copy-paste your code an it's work. So the problem is in the vectors. I change the fit to np.ones((50000,50,1)), [np.ones((50000,50,1)), np.ones((50000,1))]) and it also works. So the problem are my vectors.

Comment: Originally my vectors shape are: (50000,50) and (50000,). My sequences are 2d vectors and I transform to 3d with X = np.array(sequence)
X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], X.shape[1], -1))
 And the tag y = df.number.tolist()
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
y = np.array(y)
y = y.reshape(-1,1)
y = scaler.fit_transform(y)

Comment: Can you please attach the stack trace of the error and the version of Keras/Tensorflow?

Comment: Also, are you running this as a script from the terminal or in a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: I'm running this on google colab. And the versions are: Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.14.0 and Name: Keras
Version: 2.2.5 Also I'm going to write a coment witch the complete error

Answer (score 0):

This are the errros:
Error 1):

```
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
(0) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'decode_output_sample_weights_32' with dtype float and shape [?]
[[{{node decode_output_sample_weights_32}}]]
 [[loss_2/second_output_loss/Mean_3/_3217]]
  (1) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'decode_output_sample_weights_32' with dtype float and shape [?]
     [[{{node decode_output_sample_weights_32}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

Error 2):

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'decode_output_target_17' with dtype float and shape [?,?,?] [[{{node decode_output_target_17}}]]
```

Error 3):

```
UnknownError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv1d_1/convolution}}]]
     [[loss/add/_157]]
  (1) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv1d_1/convolution}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

Error 4):

```
UnknownError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv1d_25/convolution}}]]
     [[loss_6/second_output_loss/Mean_3/_1025]]
  (1) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv1d_25/convolution}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```